Unable to use sideBar as package 'ag-grid-enterprise' has not been imported. Check that you have imported the package
I am working on a project where I need to support both old and new versions of AG Grid. To manage this, I have set up aliases in my package.json:
"dependencies": {
  "ag-grid-community-latest": "npm:ag-grid-community@32.1.0",
  "ag-grid-enterprise-latest": "npm:ag-grid-enterprise@32.1.0",
  "ag-grid-react-latest": "npm:ag-grid-react@32.1.0",
  "ag-grid-community": "20.0.0",
  "ag-grid-enterprise": "20.0.0",
  "ag-grid-react": "20.0.0",
  // other dependencies
}

This setup allows me to use the old version of AG Grid for legacy code and the latest version for new code. However, I am encountering an issue where the enterprise features of the latest version (ag-grid-enterprise-latest) are not working. Specifically, I am getting the following error in the console:

AG Grid: Unable to use sideBar as package 'ag-grid-enterprise' has not been imported. Check that you have imported the package.

New Version Component
In my new version component, I am importing the latest versions as follows:
import 'ag-grid-enterprise-latest'; // Importing the new enterprise package
import 'ag-grid-community-latest/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community-latest/styles/ag-theme-quartz.css';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react-latest';
import { LicenseManager } from 'ag-grid-enterprise-latest';

// Set the license key
LicenseManager.setLicenseKey('license-key');

// Row Data Interface
interface IRow {
  make: string;
  model: string;
  price: number;
  electric: boolean;
}

const TestManagementGrid = () => {
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([
    { make: 'Tesla', model: 'Model Y', price: 64950, electric: true },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'F-Series', price: 33850, electric: false },
    { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Corolla', price: 29600, electric: false },
  ]);

  const [colDefs, setColDefs] = useState<any[]>([
    { field: 'make' },
    { field: 'model' },
    { field: 'price' },
    { field: 'electric' },
  ]);

  return (
    <div className='ag-theme-quartz' style={{ height: 500, width: '100%' }}>
      <AgGridReact
        rowData={rowData}
        columnDefs={colDefs}
        sideBar={true}
        statusBar={{
          statusPanels: [
            { statusPanel: 'agTotalAndFilteredRowCountComponent' },
            { statusPanel: 'agTotalRowCountComponent' },
            { statusPanel: 'agFilteredRowCountComponent' },
            { statusPanel: 'agSelectedRowCountComponent' },
            { statusPanel: 'agAggregationComponent' },
          ],
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default TestGrid;

Issue
Despite importing ag-grid-enterprise-new, the enterprise features such as the sidebar are not working, and the console throws the error mentioned above.
What I Have Tried
Checked Imports: Ensured that ag-grid-enterprise-new is imported at the top of the component file.
Tested Without Aliases: When I remove the old versions from package.json, the new versions work fine without any problems
